# half yours and half hers

Tags: sentence-construction, predicate, attributives

> "I remember that you had sent me a photo with half yours and half hers photos."

In a sentence like above, I know using collage will be a better option. But I would like to know if this construction is correct or not. It does sound a little odd though.
Are there any ways to correct this sentence in this same construction if it is incorrect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you say **hers photos**? No. You would say **her photos**... or if it's already clear what you are talking about, you would say **hers** without specifying photos.

So you first have to establish that you are talking about photos by saying **half your photos** and then you can say **hers**.

> I remember [that] you sent me a photo with half your photos and half hers

And you are right, collage or photo-collage would be a better term to use for the composite photo.

If you would like some technical terms, [her](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/her) is an attributive adjective and [hers](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hers) is a predicate adjective.